# Set a custom favicon for different google spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, favicon

I use a lot of different google spreadsheets for day to day tasks.
Sometimes all of them are open at once, and combined with other websites needed it's a lot of open tabs, so the tab header is only the sheets favicon.

I'm looking for a way to add a custom favicon to each spreadsheet using Google Apps Script, to make it easier to identify them when only the icon is visible.

I've found a Chrome extension (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/favicon-changer/ijaabbaphikljkkcbgpbaljfjpflpeoo) which changes the favicon to a specific file I choose, but I need a way to do it natively to each spreadsheet so that it works on any computer.

There's also a different extension which also changes the favicon, but to a random one you can't choose (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/favidenticon-for-google-d/alkonpgilhahbbhihdjnamkmckfajmjo).

Since theres a way to code it in an extension, I'm wondering if there's a way to code it directly in Google Apps Script, assigning a specific file as the favicon.

I've fonund also that there's a setFaviconUrl(iconUrl) method in Class HtmlOutput, but I think it's for Web Apps, I've tried using it but haven't managed to make it work:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output#setfaviconurliconurl

I have the icon files uploaded to a website in case that's needed (this is one of them https://www.botix.com.ar/imagenes-empresa/favicon-pedidos.ico)

I know little about code, so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that it is not possible at this moment. The extension you mentioned probably does not work with Google Apps Script and it may be modifying or working with Chrome specific settings or tools.

Since Google Apps Script is not able to work with Chrome related tools or APIs it would not be possible to use Google Apps Script to accomplish this. That is why the only options available are related to Chrome extensions or for web apps as you mentioned.

You can submit this as a feature request for Google Apps Script using [this link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#developer_product_feedback)